# rsync and ssh to NAS to update permissions on last copied file

Tags: macos, ssh, rsync, synology

I have a Synology DS413, which I store music, movies, etc. on.  If I download a file on my Windows machine, I can move it over via the SMB-mounted share, and permissions are handled with no issue.  From my MacBook, using any protocol (NFS, AFP, SMB), the file gets copied with 000 set.

I made a script to copy those files over, which I will paste below.  However, it's inefficient in that it runs chmod on every file in the directory after running rsync, when I really only need to set it on that last file.  Given that the script is using two distinct commands, is there a way to use mtime or something similar to only modify the most recent file?

The rsync path is because it was easier to just do a sideload of OSX's version of rsync onto the NAS using ipkg rather than trying to replace the stock one.  Similarly, there's a problem using relative paths, so absolute paths have to be used.

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/syno/bin/rsync -PavO -e 'ssh -p 42 -i /Users/stephonovich/.ssh/whoisit' . 192.168.1.186:/volume1/movies/Torrents
ssh -p 42 -i ~/.ssh/whoisit 192.168.1.186 'cd /volume1/movies/Torrents && chmod 775 *.torrent && chown rutorrent *.torrent && chgrp users *.torrent'
```

Comment: you can run `chmod` and `chown` only on the requested files. You know [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command?

Comment: Anyway you can add `--chmod`, `--chown` and `--chgrp` switches to `rsync` command to do all of it in one command and don't waste cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job for you:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/syno/bin/rsync -PavO -e \
  --chmod=F775 --chown=rutorrent:users \ 
  'ssh -p 42 -i ~/.ssh/whoisit' . 192.168.1.186:/volume1/movies/Torrents
```

For further reading, there is manual page for [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: This is the result from that script:

`rsync: Invalid argument passed to --chmod (775)
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1505) [client=3.0.9]`

If I replace 775 with `ug=rwx,o=-w`, I get errors on chown.

EDIT: Apparently those were added in rsync-3.1.0, and this is 3.0.9.  I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: I updated the answer. Check the manual page if something else does not work. If you have some other error, please post the exact line you used and error you got.

Comment: Tried compiling rsync-3.1.0 through 3.1.2, no go.  [In reading](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bup-list/oe9qq0eEr-8), apparently the libraries that optware includes for the NAS are missing something, so the build fails, thus I can't use anything passing chmod/chown/chgrp with rsync.

I think I'll try to work something out with find.